# include a class from a different website in laravel new project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, require

I am working on a backend api using laravel 5.6
Already have a website with tons of code - all the answers I found point at create a new folder and adding my classes there that is not an option.
I would like to include the class from the main site (same server) and use the methods within laravel to generate the data from the api.

```
 Route::get('api/author/full/', array('uses' => 'AuthorController@getAuthor'));
```

I am using this line to include my class:

```
require_once('/var/www/html/modules/author/models/Author.class.php');
```

laravel is located in a subfolder at `/var/www/html/api/`

this is the error I get when i try to require that file from within the AuthorController :

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method ErrorException::getStatusCode() in  /html/api/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 61

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException::getStatusCode() in  /html/api/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 61
```

really tried everything here,included it in public/index.php and in other places and none of these things worked.

Comment: Does the Author class have any dependencies?  If so, have you set up those dependencies in your Laravel project?  It seems like you may have incompatible dependencies based on the error.

Comment: no. I for example included a config.php file that is located outside laravel and when I try to echo out a value of a var $test for simplicity it returns the same error you see above. it seems like its including the file but not able to access whats inside.

Comment: if you wonder how i know its finding the file? if i change the filename and put a file that doesnt exist i get an error that the file was not found. So the file is found and included but I cant access whats inside

Comment: I would try auto loading the file through the `composer.json` file.

Comment: the file has dependencies other files it includes etc.